# How do I limit at most one instance per category per image for Faster RCNN or Yolo object detection?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, combinatorics

There are N object categories.  In both train and test sets, each input image cannot have more than 1 instance per category.

Imagine you have a chessboard with at most 1 piece of each type (e.g. 1 black rook, 1 black pawn etc).  You want your object detector to take advantage of the fact there is at most 1 instance of each type.  Note: not all types have to be present in an image.

How do I place such a constraint into Faster RCNN (or Yolo, or any other deep learning object detection network)?  It should not depend on any post-processing heuristics.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use a pre-trained model, I don't see any way to do this. But, if you are planning to train it from scratch or finetune it, make changes to the loss function so that this condition is satisfied.

Comment: Thanks but how would one modify the loss function to satisfy the constraint?  Suppose the network predicted 2 instances of the same category.  It's not clear which node the "duplicate instance loss" should back prop from.

Comment: The simplest way is only backpropagating through the highest confidence one of the both instances. But you can take it a step further and penalize the model for predicting a second instance.